# MS Teams Message[BETA] API, Retry-after header not present intermittently for 429 error case

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am using this API:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages
Content-type: application/json

{
  "body": {
    "content": "Hello World"
  }
}
```

[create message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-1-hello-world)

To create a message with in a channel for a team in a script, and received 429 error for the same API.

I am trying to use the **retry-after header** for 429 error, but seems like the **retry-after header** is not present  intermittently for the same API.

Comment: Just cross verified,  API is responding as designed. 
What time did you set in "retry-after". Probably limit is getting exhausted.

Comment: Moreover this api does not support "retry-after" header. Please check [throttling limit guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#best-practices-to-handle-throttling)